# Are web3.js & ethers.js compatible with ink! smart contracts?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I am pretty new to Substrate and wonder if we can communicate with ink! smart contracts via established libraries such as *web3.js* or *ethers.js*? Is the underlying RPC-based communication the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the underlying RPC-based communication is not the same. There is an interesting discussion in the Polkadot Forum you might want to follow: [WrappedEVM Eth RPC compatibility layer](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/wrappedevm-eth-rpc-compatibility-layer/2775).

The alternative in substrate is `polkadotjs`, and more specifically for ink! smart contracts the library **useink**. Check the documentation of useink here: https://use.ink/frontend/overview